# How can I ensure that the photo picked by imagePickerController and camera goes into DetailViewController UIImage?

Tags: swift, debugging, uikit, assert, photoeditorsdk

Image user picks in `UIImagePickerController` and camera both not working.  Where is the `[assert]` bug coming from?

Here is my Code :

ViewController :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var takePicture: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var editPhoto: UIButton!
    
    var pictures = [String]()
    
    @IBAction func takePicture(_ sender: UIButton) {
        camera()
        if let vb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vb, animated: true)
    }
        presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: actionClose)
    }
    
    @IBAction func editPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        photoGallery()
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
        presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func camera() {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .camera
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
        actionClose()
    }
    
    @objc func photoGallery() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
        actionClose()
    }

    @objc func actionClose() {
       presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
     }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
    }


}
```

DetailViewController :

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var slider1: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var slider2: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var slider3: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var slider4: UISlider!
    var currentImage: UIImage!
    
    var context: CIContext!
    var currentFilter: CIFilter!
    
    var selectedImage: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Photo Editor"
        
        context = CIContext()
        currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        dismiss(animated: true)
        print("No image found")
        currentImage = image
        
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: currentImage)
        currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
        
        applyProcessing()
    }
    
    func applyProcessing() {
        let inputKeys = currentFilter.inputKeys
        
        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(currentFilter.outputImage!, from: currentFilter.outputImage!.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            self.imageView.image = processedImage
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you, hoping you can help.

Comment: I think you didn't setup photo and camera entitlements in your app and/or are not checking permissions and/or not asking for permissions if they are not set. At least not in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

the error part is

here you present camera and push to DetailViewController at the same time change your code to this

```
 @IBAction func takePicture(_ sender: UIButton) {
        camera() //do this only
  }


    @IBAction func editPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
      //remove open photo gallery
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
       }
      presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I have done exactly what you have told me, and have added both camera and photo library usage descriptions in info.plist.  Picture taken or chosen in photo library not going into UIImage in DetailViewController.

Comment: pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x135014c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
2022-07-24 10:49:43.720105+0100 APP[32341:1234466] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-07-24 10:49:46.139227+0100 APP[32341:1234466] [Assert] UIKit Internal bug: Unbalanced call to _endOcclusion, please file a Radar on UIKit | Presentations with reproduction steps if you hit this !

Comment: Here is my bug above

Comment: you error part I defined you present UIImagePickerController and push to detailView controller at the same time why?

Comment: That's because I wanted to change to a view controller for my editing process, since my ViewController and DetailViewController looks entirely different.  I don't understand it (sorry, I'm new), what code should I use instead to ensure that doesn't happen? Thanks.